# React form submitting before submit button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, forms, dom-events

I have a very simple React application that is exhibiting odd behavior:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export function App(props) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert("Submitted!")
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      { ready ?
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> :
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setReady(true)}>Next</button> }
    </form>
  )
}
```

<sup>https://playcode.io/1741452</sup>

When I click the "Next" button, I expect the "Submit" button to appear but instead the form's `onSubmit` handler is triggered! What is causing this to occur, since the "Submit" button is never clicked?

Comment: What happens if you move button to be outside of the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some digging and found the source of the issue. ([This page](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state) was helpful in explaining things.)

It turns out that rendering the same component in the same position in the UI tree causes React to reuse the underlying DOM element. So in the example above, the `<button>` element is reused when re-rendered after `ready` is set to `true`.

The correct way to avoid this is to set the `key` attribute on the two `<button>` elements:

```
// ...
{ ready ?
  <button key="submit" type="submit">Submit</button> :
  <button key="next" type="button" onClick={() => setReady(true)}>Next</button> }
// ...
```

With this change, the expected behavior is observed.

Incidentally, this is why the `key` attribute is required when rendering a list of elements (using `.map()` for example) — to ensure that each item maintains correct state when items are added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Update your button as Below:

```
<button type="button" onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  setReady(true)
}}>Next</button>
```

Need to set "e.preventDefault()" for each button event.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this necessary? The default action of a button with `type="button"` is not to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `visibility` CSS to do the same, I am not sure why this happens, but this also solves your issue!

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export function App(props) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false)

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert("Submitted!")
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
      <button type="submit" style={{visibility: ready ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}}>Submit</button> :
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setReady(true)}>Next</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

[play code](https://playcode.io/1741469)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the code to bring out the Submit button from the form and conditionally display the next button based on the value of ready state:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Submitted!");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {ready ? <button type="submit">Submit</button> : null}
      </form>
      {!ready && <button type="button" onClick={() => setReady(true)}>Next</button>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add preventDefault to the Next button as well.

Here is a working example.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/form-submission-forked-r3s3cl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A2%2C1-32%2C1